# Convert string to DateTime nullable variable in one line

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

How can I write

```
string date = "12/2/2011";

DateTime? dt = date ?? DateTime.Parse(date);
```

this throws a compile time error. I know I can do `tryparse or do if {}`. Is there any way to do this in one line?

Comment: You have an extra question mark there. It should be `DateTime? dt = date ? DateTime.Parse(date) : null;`

Comment: sorry, just edited the question to date ?? DateTime.Parse(date) from date ?? null : DateTime.Parse(date)

Comment: Nope, C# supports the ?? operator (called elvis operator in Groovy). It returns the right side value only if the value is null, otherwise returns the value itself.

Comment: @EvertonAgner Interesting. In C# it's called "The Null Coalescing Operator". I like Elvis more.

Comment: You are having a compilation error because you are assigning a string to a DateTime. As the others described the ?? return the object if it is not null, which is the case in your code.

Comment: In Groovy it's called "Elvis Operator" because it's simbol is `?:` :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) `?:` instead of the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`:

```
DateTime? dt = date == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(date);
```

You also need to cast the null to `DateTime?` otherwise you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 3):

```
string date = "12/2/2011";

DateTime? dt = String.IsNullOrEmpty(date) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution not only assigns `null` to the nullable DateTime `dt` when the string `date` is `null` or an empty string, but also when it contains an invalid date representation:

```
string date = null; // or "01/02/2011"
DateTime? dt;

DateTime temp;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out temp)) {
    dt = temp;
} else {
    dt = null;
}
```

The if-else statement can be replaced by a one line ternary expression, however not the declaration of `temp`:

```
DateTime temp;
dt = DateTime.TryParse(date, out temp) ? temp : (DateTime?)null;
```

Comment: Downvoter please comment. What is wrong with my solution? It will not only detect when date is null, but also when it does not contain a valid date string. Note also that dt is nullable.

Comment: I just see no reason for your `else` statement, since dt is null from the start.

Comment: @EvertonAgner: Only if `dt` is a member variable, but not if it is a local variable. From the example given in the question, I do not see, whether `dt` is defined in a class or in a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
string date = "12/2/2011";
date = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```